# can .bat windows file can be configured on control-M

Tags: java, control-m

I have the java program which will be triggered from windows .bat file (having call to java program and requires JRE 1.6 on the client machine(calling machine) to run the java program.

Is that possible to configure this job on control-M? I am not sure how the control- M configuration of a job will be done, hence wanted to know if we will be able to install JRE 1.6 or above on the Control-M machine and is possible to run the .bat file from control-M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It's possible to run a bat from Control-M and get the return code to stablish the ending state of the Job.

Complete information about how it works in the BMC Control-M Manual: http://www.scheduler-usage.com/document/Version/630/Books/MAW620300AG52365.pdf

---

JRE Must be installed in the machine before to work with good performance and with a correct environment.

You probably can check if JRE 1.6 is installed in the bat and install it but it's a complicated process with probably thirdparty tools and use of silent JRE install. Not recommended, it's better to have JRE installed as requirement to run the job.

Comment: Thanks @Dubas for my one of the question. My program runs with jre 1.6 or above. is there any step that control-m job asks for JRE version while configuring a job

Comment: @mahesh that question makes no sense. control-m runs a batch file, it's the batch file that is using JRE to run the java program. Thus, you'd have to modify the batch file for this. Also, installing JRE on a machine Control-M runs on depends on the machine and its operating system, not on Control-M.

Comment: also, weather a .bat file can be run depends on the operating system Control-M job is running on. It would need Windows operating system.

Comment: I am planing to have the .bat file have the PATH set to jre installed on the machine from where the .bat file will be required to execute